# Reversing an array stored in State doesnt force re-render of component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

This is part of a larger component but I've summarised it in a reproducible example below:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react'

   
    function App() {
        const [data,setData] = useState([{name:'first'},{name:'second'},{name:'three'}])

       // Function to reverse a given array
        const reverseArray = (array) => {
          var reverseArray = array.reverse();
          return reverseArray;
        }


        return (
            <div>
                  {data.map((item,index)=>{
                         return <h1 key={index}>{item.name} index: {index}</h1>
                    })}
            

                    {/*When I click this I expect the div above to rerender */}
                    <button onClick={()=>{
                        var newData = data;
                        setData(reverseArray(newData))}
                    }>
                      Reverse Order
                     </button>

                    {/* Logs state to the console to check order is reversed */}
                    <button onClick={()=>console.log(data)}>Log Data</button>

                    {/* Clearing the state by setting to empty array */}
                    <button onClick={()=>setData([ ])}>Clear Data</button>

                    
            </div>
        )
    }
```

So my main issue, is that the mapped data doesn't seem to change with a state update.
As a check that state does update, I have a clear button which does clear the data state and the list goes blank.

When I click the reverse button, I expect the data to be reversed (i.e. "first" to be last and "three" to be in first place).
I'm sure my state is updated as I can check it with console logs before and after the reverse button is clicked.

My thought process was to create a completely new reversed array (newData) and set this as the state. However, the mapping doesn't reflect this order change. What am I missing here?

I understand components in React will rerender when state changes, why does setting a new array to state not trigger this? But the rerender is apparent when clearing the state?

My sandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-sun-oujqj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/array-reverse-react-state-0v67h

[`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses the elements in place. You'll need to pass a new array into `setData()`.

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    var newData = data;

    // Create a new array using the spread operator
    setData(reverseArray([...newData])); 
  }}
>
```

Comment: Perfect! So does declaring `var newData` not actually make a copy of the array, but rather reverses the elements in place? Even though it is a separate variable?

Comment: @yahms23 `newData` does not make a copy, it simply adds a handle that points to the exact same array (`newData` is essentially an alias for `data`). See: [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

The reason React is not re-rendering the component is because `Array.prototype.reverse` mutates the array and return the reference

For Example

```
    const array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    const revArray = array.reverse() // This will reverse 'array' variable and returns it's reference
    
    array === revArray // this statement is true
    console.log(array) // result [5,4,3,2,1]
    console.log(revArray) // result [5,4,3,2,1]
```

In the above `array === revArray` because both are referring to the same array,
Since that is the case, The state is not actually changing because the referrence to the array is same.

**Solution:**
Simply return a new Array!

```
 const reverseArray = (array) => {
      const revArray = array.reverse();
      return [...revArray] 
    }
```